# Mail Merge in Microsoft Word with images from Sharepoint

Tags: microsoft-word, sharepoint, mail-merge

Is there any way of doing a Mail Merge in Microsoft Word 2007 taking data, including images from a Sharepoint site? It's a bit crude, but I've managed to merge text by taking the data off the sharepoint site as an Excel sheet and then merging that. My problem is what to do with the images. I can set references to the images up in the Sharepoint site, however all I can find is a way of Mail Merging when images are in the same folder as the document you are trying to Merge and I can't find a sensible automated way to pulls these images together into one single folder.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no. Office mail merge does not support HTTP connections.

Accept this and use a file share.